# While statement has no body?

Tags: java, loops, syntax, while-loop

I have a number of statements in one procedure like this:

```
while( x + ++flips < 8 && board[x + flips][y] == opponent );
```

The (standard "Oracle") compiler is returning the error: "While statement has no body." Is this required by the language specification, or is it compiler specific? Is there some kind of hack I can use to get this to work or am I stuck rewriting it?

Comment: I don't know, would appending `while(..) {};` work maybe?

Comment: Add a body - `{ /* this does nothing */}` - to shut it up. It is debatable if this is an *error* (perhaps only for n00bs) or a matter of consistency.

Comment: [A very similar loop works when I try it.](http://ideone.com/LDfLbd) Are you sure you have the semicolon in the right place in your actual code?

Comment: Another good solution is to write readable code. Personally I hate such ugly statements.

Comment: You could consider writing a body rather than misusing the condition.

Comment: [Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html) **and** [*Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live*](http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/).

Comment: OP, is it possible that you are confusing an IDE warning for a compiler error?

Comment: @Misha It does appear to be some kind of warning that the IDE is morphing into an error.

Comment: @TylerDurden You said that this is an Oracle compiler error. I don't believe that to be true - this is not an error that javac emits. (Try searching for `javac "while statement has no body"` on Google). If it's an IDE warning, then update your question to make it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an empty body. Like this `while( x + ++flips < 8 && board[x + flips][y] == opponent ){}`.

Comment: The semicolon should already suffice as a body. The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.12) allows it, and it compiles fine when I try it.

Answer (score 5):

The code you've posted [compiles fine when I try it](http://ideone.com/AqV7s1), and [JLS section 14.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.12) allows an empty statement as the body of a `while` loop:

```
WhileStatement:
  while ( Expression ) Statement

Statement:
  StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement 
  ...

StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
  Block 
  EmptyStatement
  ...

EmptyStatement:
  ;
```

Most likely, your actual code has a typo.